AWS cloudwatch monitoring for perfmon counters
Im trying to monitor a windows perfmon counter with AWS cloudwatch agents. However i seem to hit a bit of a brickwall where i cant seem to get anywhere.
In particular i am trying to monitor the MSMQ object in perfmon and am interested in the messages in que counter.
snippet of counter in perfmon
From documentation I have found there's a couple of different contradicting ways of doing this.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-performance-monitor-windows
this documentation would suggest that adding this:

"PerformanceCounter-Family(processor, logical disk, memory etc.)": {  
  "measurement": [
      "Counter-name ("%Usage, "% free space" etc.)"
    ],
  "metrics_collection_interval": 30,
  "resources": [
    "Counter Property ( "_total", "C:/" etc.)
  ]
},

for additional counters would resolve this issue. Unfortunately this hasnt been the case :D maybe im implementing this wrong...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html
Within the complete example there is a given example of monitoring a counter object as shown below:

          "customizedObjectName": {
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "customizedCounterName": [
              "metric1",
              "metric2"
            ],
            "resources": [
              "customizedInstances"
            ]
          },


which again sounds right but again hasnt resolved my issue....
If someone could share some light if they have been able to do something like this or monitor MSMQ using a different aws CW plugin then it would be greatly appreciated :)

Ok finally figured this out was likely a initial issue on my end. However, the documentation isn't particularly helpful..... but regardless my solution is as below:
  "MSMQ Queue": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 30,
    "measurement": [
      "Messages in Queue"
    ],
    "resources": [
      "*"
    ]
  }

